# Converting line of code from VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, ctype

I am trying to convert a block of code from VB to C# but am running into an issue w/ one line of code.

VB Code:

```
Dim tsAV As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip = 
    CType(objHost.FormMain.Controls("tsMain"), Windows.Forms.ToolStrip)
```

Code I have in C#:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip tsAV = 
    (System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip)objHost.FormMain;
```

My problem comes in on the FormMain method. When I use VB code I can get the Controls method but in C# I cannot. I use the same Interface DLL included both ways.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is it possible for a DLL to include certain things that only work in VB?

Comment: What is objHost? What is the type of this variable?

Comment: what is `FormMain` - a class or instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use this as your C# code:

```
// using System.Windows.Forms;
ToolStrip tsAV = (ToolStrip)objHost.FormMain().Controls["tsMain"];
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In your example you are trying to cast the `Form` as a `ToolStrip`, that won't work.

Comment: My issue is that Visual Studio yells at me saying "FormMain is a Method and cannot be used in this context" when writing it out like you have it in C#. In VB it works just fine.

Comment: VB is more forgiving with not using parentheses on method calls. C# is not, when it tells you that you should just need to add the parentheses to the method call. I have updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Wow, could have sworn I tried that haha but it worked! Thanks a ton for your help! Still learning lol :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve a ToolStrip in a c# Form, you can use the following code. This assumes that the ToolStrip name is "tsAV" and that you are executing this code from a method within `FormMain` (which is presumably the class name of the main form).

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
...
ToolStrip tsAV = (ToolStrip)Controls["tsMain"];
```

From outside of the form, you can find the ToolStrip by using the following code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
...
FormMain form = new FormMain();
ToolStrip tsAV = (ToolStrip)form.Controls["tsMain"];
```

Update: Assuming that `objHost` is a controller of sorts and `FormMain` is a field or property name that returns an *instance* of a form, rather than a class name, you can use the following:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
...
ToolStrip tsAV = (ToolStrip)objHost.FormMain.Controls["tsMain"];
```